# Illustrator Layers to Photoshop Layers

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I know this question has been asked before, but to no avail, am still not able to export into Photoshop without getting a flattened file.

1. I released (sequenced) all layers in the file.
2. Exported the .ai layered file as .psd, with Use All Artboards checked, and with Write layers checked. Before I save, I get a popup that says "Some containers in the .ai file have been flattened".
3. I open up the file in Photoshop, and sure enough, the entire doc has been flattened".
4. I even tried not checking the "Use All Artboards" box.

Please help, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You must not use *any* transparency or blending modes. Using either will flatten AI layers.

Comment: Would having a few transparency layers really cause the entire document to be flattened though? I was able to test this process earlier, and MOST of the layers exported. Just not all of them. (scratching my head)

Comment: Yes. Generally anything with transparency and *below* it will be flattened.

Comment: So as a test, I eliminated object with any transparency or gradient. But those objects are still flattening even though they are the top layers in the documents. Thinking I may have to purchase a smart layer plugin.

Comment: Be aware, glows, blurs, drop shadows, etc. will create transparency as well. Basically it comes down to the Appearance settings. Some appearance items cause what is below them to be flattened in order to maintain the overall visual appearance.

Comment: Can these be deactivated in the transparency menu, or does that option have to be deleted entirely?

Comment: To be honest, I'm uncertain. I *think* merely deactivating them will work since they won't *visually* be there and thus not warrant any alteration to layers below them.

Comment: Oh and you also need to be certain you are exporting to the **same** color mode as the AI document. Don't export a CMYK Illustrator file to an RGB Photoshop file or vice versa. Always RGB to RGB and CMYK to CMYK.

Comment: Okay, so I did the test with the first group of layers eliminating any transparencies, gradients and grouping of layers. For the most part, it has worked, but is still flattening some of my elements that are enclosed in folders. This is a partial victory!

Comment: Scott, THANK YOU, THANK YOU! I'd give a big hug if I could. Double checked some hidden transparencies...and deleted dropshadows...and it WORKED!!!! :-)

Comment: Glad I could help. `:)`

Comment: You are amazing! Now i can have a great weekend. You do too!

Answer (score 1):

You **must** remove all transparency before exporting.

This includes glows, drops shadows, blurs, **any** blending modes, opacity, etc. **Anything** which introduces transparency will cause all layers below it to flatten in order to maintain the visual appearance.

In addition, **always** export to the **same** color mode as the AI file. RGB to RGB and CMYK to CMYK. Never try and cross color modes with the export. (You can always change the mode in Photoshop once you get a good export)